# Get string from Regex in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I need to add a string to a regular expression in ruby, this is what Im trying to do (Im getting all the files in my directory, opening them, finding if they have a pattern, then modifying that pattern by adding to what already exists, to do this I need the actual string)

```
Dir["*"].each do |tFile|
  file = File.open(tFile, "rb")
  contents = file.read
  imageLine=/<img class="myclass"(.*)\/>/
  if(contents=~imageLine)
      puts contents.sub!(imageLine, "some string"+imageLine+"some other string")
  end
end
```

Comment: I think you need to open the File with write permissions, `File.open(tFile, 'rw')` and iterate each line of the file, replacing the line where you find the pattern.

Comment: You open with write if you're writing to it. Here the `puts` is going to STDOUT.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sub` or `gsub` with capture groups:

```
"foo".gsub(/(o)/, '\1x')
=> "foxox"
```

For more information, consult [the docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-gsub).

Answer (score 0):

You're using `sub!` which is the in-place modifier version. While this has its uses, the result of the method is not the string but an indication if anything was done or not.

The `sub` method is more appropriate for this case. If you have multiple matches that have to be replaced, use `gsub`.

When doing substitution you can either use the placeholders like `\1` to work with captured parts, where you capture using brackets in your regular expression, or the employ the block version to do more arbitrary manipulation.

```
IMAGE_REGEXP = /<img class="myclass"(.*)\/>/

Dir["*"].each do |tFile|
  File.open(tFile, "rb") do |in|
    puts in.read.gsub(IMAGE_REGEXP) { |s| "some string#{s}some other string" }
  end
end
```